# Find an specific word on a file, get the content of the row, and save it on a array

Tags: python, file

I've a .xls file that I convert to .csv, and then read this .csv until one specific line that contains the word `clientegen`, get that row and put it on a array.

This is my code so far:

```
import xlrd
import csv

def main():
    print "Converts xls to csv and reads csv"
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('ejemplo.xls')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
    archivo_csv = open('fichero_csv.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(archivo_csv, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
    archivo_csv.close()

    f = open('fichero_csv.csv', 'r')
    for lines in f:
        print lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This prints me:

```
[... a lot of more stuff ...]

"marco 4","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

"clientegen","maier","embega","Jegan ","tapa pure","cil HUF","carcHUF","tecla NSS","M1 NSS","M2 nss","M3 nss","doble nss","tapon","sagola","clip volvo","pillar"

"pz/bast","33.0","40.0","34.0","26.0","80.0","88.0","18.0","16.0","8.0","6.0","34.0","252.0","6.0","28.0","20.0"

"bast/Barra","5.0","3.0","6.0","8.0","10.0","4.0","10.0","10.0","10.0","10.0","8.0","4.0","6.0","10.0","6.0"

[... a lot of more stuff ...]
```

The thing I want to do is take that `clientegen` line, and save the content of the row on a new string array with the name `finalarray` for example.

```
finalarray = ["maier", "embega", "Jegan", "tapa pure", "cil HUF", "carcHUF", "tecla NSS", "M1 NSS", "M2 nss", "M3 nss", "doble nss", "tapon", "sagola", "clip volvo", "pillar"]
```

I'm not a lot into python file's read/read so I would like to know how if someone could give me a hand to find that line, get those values and put them on a array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you swap this for loop out for your for loop, it should do the trick:

```
    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        row = sh.row_values(rownum)
        if row[0] == "clientegen":  # Check if "clientgen" is the first element of the row
            finalarray = list(row)  # If so, make a copy of it and name it `finalarray`
        wr.writerow(row)
```

If there will ever be more than one "clientegen" line, we can adjust this code to save all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the line that contains `clientegen`, then you could try:

```
finalarray = list()
with open("fichero_csv.csv") as f:
  for line in f: #loop through all the lines
    words = line.split(" ") #get a list of all the words
    if "clientegen" in words: #check to see if your word is in the list
      finalarray = words #if so, put the word list in your finalarray
      break  #stop checking any further
```